# How to get font settings from CSS file to Font object?

Tags: css, javafx

I would like to get a font settings from a CSS file:

```
#myCustomFont
{
  -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI";
  -fx-font-size: 14px;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
  -fx-text-fill: red;
 }
```

and then pass it as a parameter in several methods as **Font** object. For this, I used the auxiliary **Text** object:

```
Text t = new Text("Some text");
t.setId("myCustomFont");
t.applyCss();
Font myFont = t.getFont();
```

Unfortunately font **myFont** is not like in the CSS file, it has remained the default.
The same problem is with setting the font in the **Label** object created in code similarly to the above, but if **Label** is  implemented in **fxml** file of my project, font **myFont2** is like in CSS:

```
 dateTimeLabel.setText("12.01.2022"); //Label from .fxml
 dateTimeLabel.setId("myCustomFont");
 dateTimeLabel.applyCss();
 Font myFont2 = dateTimeLabel.getFont(); //OK
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This works as expected for me.

The node on which CSS is being applied should be in a scene before the CSS is applied to it.

See the documentation for [applyCss()](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss()):

> This method is a no-op if the Node is not in a Scene. The Scene does not have to be in a Stage.

The example application will output to the command line, the following value:

```
Font[name=Comic Sans MS Bold, family=Comic Sans MS, style=Bold, size=40.0]
```

Tested on OS X, JavaFX 17.0.1.

**Example App**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FontTemplate extends Application {
    private static final String CUSTOM_FONT_CSS = """
            data:text/css,
            #customFont {
                -fx-font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
                -fx-font-size: 40px;
                -fx-font-weight: bold;
                -fx-text-fill: red;
            }
            """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label label = new Label("Label");
        label.getStylesheets().add(CUSTOM_FONT_CSS);
        label.setId("customFont");

        Scene scene = new Scene(label);
        label.applyCss();

        System.out.println(label.getFont());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer. I completely forgot that a dynamically created label needs to be related in some way to the scene for which the style file is being set up: **scene.getStylesheets().add(relative_path_to_css_file)**

In your example You assigned a style to Label as **CUSTOM_FONT_CSS** String, but I need to read the style from the css file that is assigned to the scene, so I used this trick:

```
  Label label = new Label();
  somePane.getChildren().add(label); //some Pane located on the scene (from .fxml)
  label.setId("myCustomFont");
  label.applyCss();
  Font myFont = label.getFont();
  somePane.getChildren().remove(label); //cleaning
```

In this way, the Label becomes associated with the scene and the style file, which will make setting some #id contained in the css file work.